CMD and Powershell RAM Speed Doesn't Match Task Manager
I just noticed that the RAM speed I get from CMD or PowerShell does not return the same numbers as what Task Manager shows me:
CMD:
wmic memorychip get speed
Speed
5600
5600

PowerShell:
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory).Speed
5600
5600

Task Manager:

For some reason Task Manager shows 5200 MHz while the other two show 5600 MHz. When I boot into the BIOS, I have it set to "Auto" which the BIOS shows as corresponding to 5200 MHz.
These are two 48 GB DDR5 desktop memory sticks (96 GB total) on an AM5 MSI motherboard. This is the RAM I'm using: https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-2x48GB-5600MT-Desktop-CP2K48G56C46U5/dp/B0C79RMMCL
Any idea why they don't match? Is this something to do with the memory capacities (48 GB) not being a power of 2? I've never seen Task Manager not match the others before.
This is Windows 10 21H2.

Interesting... and when I run a stress test, the actual CPU speed shows yet another value, about double that from wmic memorychip get speed, and 1.5 * the static speed in Task Manager shown top-right.

Maybe WMIC returns the maximum speed the RAM is rated for but Task Manager returns the actual speed its operating on ?

@Silbee, for this particular set of RAM, this would appear to be the case, as it still returns 5600 even when I tried lowering the speed to 4800 in the BIOS. However, on other RAM sets (Corsair and GSkill, for example) that I had running at 4800 and had a maximum speed of 5600 or 6000, PowerShell and CMD would both return 4800; so it seems like it might depend on the hardware. It's worth noting those other RAM sets I tried were 64 GB (2 x 32 GB).

I found this command which appears to return the correct speed under Configuredclockspeed:
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Manufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Speed,Devicelocator -autosize
So I suppose this question is a difference of understanding Speed and Configuredclockspeed. As I mentioned in my prior comment, I don't think it's as simple as the difference between the rated and current speed, considering I have other RAM modules where Speed returns 4800 (which is what I have them running at ) even though they are rated as high as 5600 or 6000.

@EllipticalInitial It is indeed odd behaviour; although i dont think the RAM sticks being 48GB would be the key difference. I know too little about wmic to know how exactly each value is populated, but it might be worth throwing this question up on some microsoft forum.

I was encouraged to add my findings as an answer:
I found this command which appears to return the correct speed under Configuredclockspeed:
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table M1anufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Speed,Devicelocator -autosize
So I suppose this question is a difference of understanding Speed and Configuredclockspeed. I don't think it's as simple as the difference between the rated and current speed, considering I have other RAM modules where Speed returns 4800 (which is what I have them running at) even though they are rated as high as 5600 or 6000 MHz.
